# Setting up Pebble SDK with DOCKER

Tags: docker, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I used to develop Pebble Watch apllication with pebble Cloud.
Now, as Pebble Cloud is down, I wouild like to use Pebble SDK on Ubuntu.
I've tried to install the SDK on Ubuntu 18 but it's failed.

So I've tried to use a Docker Container but the flowing error appears :

> standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "exec format
>   error"

I have tried the following containers :

> *dmorgan81/rebble* and *bboehmke/pebble-dev* and *andredumas/pebble-dev*

If I understand the way it work's, for creating the necessary files for the development environnement you only have to launch the container with the "***pebble new-project***" command :

> docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/pebble andredumas/pebble-dev pebble
>   new-project watchtest

If somebody can help me with the use of a Docker Container with Pebble SDK it will be great !

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled quite a bit with this and I've put the result of my work in two repos on github.

Not 100% Docker related (I've used Vagrant) but I think you can use the info anyway.

This one is simple Pebble SDK, working from CLI:
https://github.com/ltpitt/vagrant-pebble-sdk

This one spawns a virtual machine with a working version of CloudPebble:
https://github.com/ltpitt/vagrant-cloudpebble-composed

Good luck and let me know if you want to help in improving what I did.

Comment: Thank's for your answer and sorry for my late comment. I can't use vagrant because I use an ARM64 machine

Comment: No worries, @AndroLogiciels! I am still here :D
In that case I suggest you to look into https://github.com/ltpitt/vagrant-pebble-sdk/blob/master/Vagrantfile you will find the commands I used to create a working Pebble SDK :)

Comment: Ps
If you really want to use docker please check: https://github.com/ManuelLR/docker-pebble-dev

Comment: oh, this seems to be very recent: https://github.com/bboehmke/docker-pebble-dev